# How to count a unique value that appears more than once with one criterion

Tags: excel-formula

I am trying to create a formula in excel that will count unique values that appear more than once based on one criterion.

| Column A | Column B | Column C |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Facility | MRN | Risk Score |
| Facility 1 | 456213 | High Risk |
| Facility 2 | 150004 | Moderate Risk |
| Facility 3 | 158182 | Moderate Risk Rising |
| Facility 3 | 158182 | Moderate Risk Rising |
| Facility 4 | 180005 | High Risk Rising |
| Facility 4 | 180005 | High Risk Rising |
| Facility 4 | 180005 | High Risk Rising |
| Facility 4 | 180005 | High Risk Rising |
| Facility 1 | 225100 | Moderate Risk |
| Facility 2 | 235361 | Low Risk Rising |
| Facility 2 | 235361 | Low Risk Rising |
| Facility 2 | 235361 | Low Risk Rising |

The formula I tried is:
=SUM(--(LEN(UNIQUE(FILTER($B:$B,($A:$A=$B7)*($C:$C=G$5),"")))>0))

The issue I am having is calculating ONLY the MRNs for each facility that appear more than once. In the above formula $B7 represents the facility name and G$5 represents Risk Score name cell location on a different worksheet.

| Facility | Risk Score | Total ## | Risk Score | Total ## |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Facility 1 | Low Risk | Total ## | Moderate Risk | Total ## |
| Facility 2 | Low Risk | Total ## | Moderate Risk | Total ## |

Comment: I can do this but with python only.

Comment: There's a couple of things that make me wonder I understand things correctly:
1) In your example data you show Column A, Column B, Column C, while in your formula and it's explanation you refer to different columns. What is preferred?
2) Your expected result mentions `Low Risk` and `Moderate Risk` for Facility 2. I expect this to be `Moderate Risk` and `Low Risk Rising`. Is this correct?
3) You have a Total column in your expected result. What is this supposed to display?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if I understood the question correctly, but this creates a filter of the Columns A to C where the count of the Risk Score for each Facility is equal to 1:

```
=LET(data;A1:C13;
                 a;INDEX(data;;1);
                 c;INDEX(data;;3);
        unique;UNIQUE(data);
                 ua;INDEX(unique;;1);
                 uc;INDEX(unique;;3);
        riskcount;COUNTIFS(a;ua;c;uc);
        FILTER(unique;riskcount=1))
```

This results in the following list (green):
[image]

I showed the unique values of columns A:C and it's count of risk scores to explain what values are returned (only the values with count of 1).

You might want to wrap the `FILTER` in `SORT` to get a sorted result

In case you don't have Office 365 you might want to use the following:
`=IFERROR(INDEX($A$2:$C$13,AGGREGATE(15,6,1/(NOT(COUNTIFS($A$2:$A$13,$A$2:$A$13,$C$2:$C$13,$C$2:$C$13)>1))*(ROW($A$2:$A$13)-ROW($A$1)),ROW($A1)),COLUMN(A$1)),"")`

Confirm with `ctrl+shift+enter` and copy down & to the right.

[image]

Comment: super nice - well done.

Comment: The problem I have in addition to finding the right formula is the excel application I have for work does not have the function - UNIQUE. I should have added that information into my question. I came up with a formula with UNIQUE but can only use it on my personal laptop.

Comment: See edit for a solution for Excel version prior to Office 365